# main dropdown with 7 sub dropdowns same name reset

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have main dropdown for days of week , each day has a sub drop down with same name. now when the form is posted we can't get the value of the selected , so we need to reset all the other submenu's and send only the real selected value

```
<select name="Todays_Day" class="form-control input-lg form-el" id="tday" required>
<option value="" selected>When do you need us?</option>
<option value="Sunday 22-10-2017" >Sunday 22-10-2017</option>
<option value="Monday 23-10-2017" >Monday 23-10-2017</option>
<option value="Tuesday 24-10-2017" >Tuesday 24-10-2017</option>
<option value="Wednesday 25-10-2017" >Wednesday 25-10-2017</option>
<option value="Thursday 26-10-2017" >Thursday 26-10-2017</option>
<option value="Friday 27-10-2017" >Friday 27-10-2017</option>
<option value="Saturday 28-10-2017" >Saturday 28-10-2017</option>
```

```
 <div style='display:none; ' id='todayt'>
<select name="date" class="form-control input-lg form-el" >    
<option value="">What time?</option>
<option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
<option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option><option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
<option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option><option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option><option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option><option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option><option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option><option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option><option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option><option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option></select>
</div>

<div style='display:none; ' id='tomorrowt'><select name="date" class="form-control input-lg form-el" >    
<option value="">What time?</option>
<option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
<option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
<option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
<option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
<option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
<option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
<option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
<option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
<option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
<option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
<option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
<option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
<option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
<option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
<option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
<option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option></select>
</div>

<div style='display:none; ' id='aftertomt'><select name="date" class="form-control input-lg form-el" >    
<option value="">What time?</option>
<option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
<option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
<option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
<option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
<option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
<option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
<option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
<option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
<option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
<option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
<option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
<option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
<option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
<option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
<option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
<option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option></select>
</div>


<div style='display:none; ' id='day4'><select name="date" class="form-control input-lg form-el" >    <option value="">What time?</option>
<option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
<option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
<option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
<option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
<option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
<option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
<option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
<option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
<option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
<option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
<option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
<option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
<option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
<option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
<option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
<option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option></select>
</div>

<div style='display:none; ' id='day5'>
<select name="date" class="form-control input-lg form-el" >  
<option value="">What time?</option>
<option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
<option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
<option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
<option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
<option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
<option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
<option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
<option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
<option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
<option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
<option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
<option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
<option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
<option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
<option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
<option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option></select>
</div>

<div style='display:none; ' id='day6'>
<select name="date" class="form-control input-lg form-el" >   
<option value="">What time?</option>
<option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
<option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
<option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
<option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
<option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
<option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
<option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
<option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
<option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
<option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
<option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
<option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
<option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
<option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
<option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
<option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option></select>
</div>

<div style='display:none; ' id='day7'>
<select name="date" class="form-control input-lg form-el" >    
 <option value="">What time?</option>
<option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
<option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
<option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
<option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
<option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
<option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
<option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
<option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
<option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
<option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
<option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
<option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
<option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
<option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
<option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
<option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option></select>
</div>                      

    <br><br>
```

When we send the form the result is empty as the selected option is

```
<option value="">What time?</option>
```

also if you select a day and time from main / sub menu's them move to another day and time on another date it will post the first value only , we need it to reset and post the last real selected option value

we need to get the result of the real selected option value only.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following solution, it keeps the current selected value and resets the others.

```js
//select the selects into an variable using querySelectorAll
var selects = document.querySelectorAll("select[name='date']");

//attach an onchange event to all selects. -- Use Array.prototype.forEach to iterate over nodelist
Array.prototype.forEach.call(selects, function(element){
  element.addEventListener("change", setPostValues);
});


function setPostValues()
{
  var self = this;
  //when element is not the changed element, reset to initial value.
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(selects, function(element){
    if (element != self)
    {
      element.value = "";
    }
  });  
}
```

```css
div{
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div style='display:none; ' id='todayt'>
<select name="date" class="form-control input-lg form-el" >    
<option value="">What time?</option>
<option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
<option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option><option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
<option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option><option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option><option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option><option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option><option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option><option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option><option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option><option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option></select>
</div>

<div style='display:none; ' id='tomorrowt'><select name="date" class="form-control input-lg form-el" >    
<option value="">What time?</option>
<option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
<option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
<option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
<option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
<option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
<option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
<option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
<option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
<option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
<option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
<option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
<option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
<option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
<option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
<option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
<option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option></select>
</div>

<div style='display:none; ' id='aftertomt'><select name="date" class="form-control input-lg form-el" >    
<option value="">What time?</option>
<option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
<option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
<option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
<option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
<option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
<option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
<option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
<option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
<option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
<option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
<option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
<option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
<option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
<option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
<option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
<option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option></select>
</div>


<div style='display:none; ' id='day4'><select name="date" class="form-control input-lg form-el" >    <option value="">What time?</option>
<option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
<option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
<option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
<option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
<option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
<option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
<option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
<option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
<option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
<option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
<option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
<option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
<option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
<option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
<option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
<option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option></select>
</div>

<div style='display:none; ' id='day5'>
<select name="date" class="form-control input-lg form-el" >  
<option value="">What time?</option>
<option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
<option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
<option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
<option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
<option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
<option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
<option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
<option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
<option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
<option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
<option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
<option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
<option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
<option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
<option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
<option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option></select>
</div>

<div style='display:none; ' id='day6'>
<select name="date" class="form-control input-lg form-el" >   
<option value="">What time?</option>
<option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
<option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
<option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
<option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
<option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
<option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
<option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
<option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
<option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
<option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
<option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
<option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
<option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
<option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
<option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
<option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option></select>
</div>

<div style='display:none; ' id='day7'>
<select name="date" class="form-control input-lg form-el" >    
 <option value="">What time?</option>
<option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
<option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
<option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
<option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
<option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
<option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
<option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
<option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
<option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
<option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
<option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
<option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
<option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
<option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
<option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
<option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option></select>
</div>                      

    <br><br>
```

Comment: I worked with what I got. My code has all the clues to finding the answers.